# Strange behavior of Event listener / Event flow

Tags: actionscript-3

In the following code, if I click on the 'button', all three function will be called.
But in all other cases, only stage event are fired.
Why the 'sprite' event didn't got fired?

```
public class EventFlowTest extends Sprite
{
    private var button:Sprite;

    public function EventFlowTest()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    }
    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,stageMouseDown,false);


        graphics.beginFill(0x11);
        graphics.drawCircle(100,100,100);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,spriteMouseDown,false);          


        button=new Sprite();
        addChild(button);

        button.graphics.beginFill(0xF1);
        button.graphics.drawCircle(100,100,10);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,buttonMouseDown,false);
    }

    private function spriteMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("sprite");
    }

    private function stageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("stage");
    }

    private function buttonMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("button");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is "Vector graphics ignored in main class instance" (mouse interactions)
http://books.google.ru/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&lpg=PA533&ots=cvPZ0qbQv8&dq=Vector%20graphics%20ignored%20in%20main-class%20instance&pg=PA533#v=onepage&q=Vector%20graphics%20ignored%20in%20main-class%20instance&f=false

Comment: In case that link's not showing up for anyone else, it's "Mouse interactions with vector content drawn via the instance variable `graphics` of a .swf file's main class do not trigger mouse events. However, mouse interactions with vector content drawn via the instance variable `graphics` or any other instance of `InteractiveObject` or it's subclasses do trigger mouse events"

Answer (score 0):

that's strange... this behavior occur when your test class is the document class.
If you embed your test in a document class, every thing is running as expected. I have no explaination for that behavior.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public function Main() {
            var test : EventFlowTest = new EventFlowTest();
            addChild(test);
        }
    }
}
```